# save credit card info by encrypting to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql

My use case is, user should be able to save credit card information like credit card number, name on card, expiry date and type of card to the database. Credit card info is very critical. It needs encryption. I know it's better to use stripe for saving those info to their server instead but currently I am not sure what platform I will be using. For temporary purpose, if i have to save those details, how should i do it? I need those **details to frontend(react application)** as well so I can show user they have following cards from which they can make a payment. I wont be showing credit card number, just the card but to make a payment i need those info to get back from the server so i can autofill those details while making payment.

Here is how I tried but for encryption i used bcrypt. Since bcrypt is one way algorithm I could not able to decode in the frontend to autofill the detail in a payment processor library.

```
const hashPassword = async (password) => {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  return await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
}


saveCard: combineResolvers(
      async (parent, { input: { userId, cardData } }, { req }) => {
        try {
          const existingUser = await req.db
            .collection('User')
            .findOne({
              _id: userId,
            });
          if (!existingUser) {
            // raise user not found error
          }
          const creditCardObj = await validateCreateCreditCardSchema(
            req,
            cardData,
          );
          creditCardObj.creditCardNumber = await hashPassword(
            cardData.creditCardNumber,
          ); // uses salted hash
          creditCardObj.userId = userId;
          const creditCardRes = await req.db
            .collection('CreditCard')
            .insertOne(creditCardObj);
          if (creditCardRes.result.n > 0) {
            // return success response
          } else {
          //  error occured message
          }
        } catch (err) {
          // internal server error
        }
      },
```

Note: I am not using any payment processor. I am just mocking the process. As I am not sure, what payment platform I will use. Stripe supports the functionality of saving card details to their server and get the list of those saved one and charge later but not sure if the platform I choose later will support this. so I just want to imitate for now by saving those details on my database and get those details to autofill as securely as possible.

Comment: payment processors generally don't store the credit card details - they store an authorization.

Comment: I think stripe has the functionality to save card details and charge later. Not sure about any other platform though.

Comment: PCI discourages storing credit card numbers: https://www.globalpaymentsintegrated.com/en-us/blog/2019/11/25/pci-rules-for-storing-credit-card-numbers-in-a-database

Comment: but stripe has the save and reuse feature (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse)

Comment: yes but they likely store things as an authorization.

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application is [PCI compliant](https://squareup.com/guides/pci-compliance) you should **NOT** be accepting any real credit card numbers **IN ANY SITUATION**.

You can accept [made up credit card numbers](https://www.getcreditcardinfo.com/index.php) so that you can, for example, develop your frontend. In this case you don't need any special security for them.

If you *must* accept real credit card numbers during development for whatever reason, you should integrate with *one* of the legitimate payment processors following all of their security guidance. Then if you wish to switch payment processors you can do so down the road.

To store any kind of sensitive information such as stripe tokens in MongoDB, you can use [client side encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/).